# Execute a command when vim exits

Tags: linux, vim, git

Is there a configuration I can add to a .vimrc file which will cause vim to run a command when a file is closed?

For instance, suppose I'm editing a file that is under version control. Once I'm done editing I would like a command to commit my changes to be run immediately before vim fully closes without having to run it separately after saving/quiting the file.

I'm curious about this as I have a tendency to forget to commit my changes.

Alternatively and if it is not possible to do what I'm asking, is it possible to configure an internal vim :command that will run the commit from with vim before I close the file?

Comment: It's not in vimrc however you could use shell &&. I use it like this:
vim a.c && gcc a.c -Wall -Werror -pedantic && ./a.out which opens file, compiles after closing and runs it. You can create a shell script to simplify it.

Answer (score 6):

Though it is not a good idea to commit changes immediately after editing and quitting the file,
you can try vim auto commands.

```
augroup autocom
    autocmd!
    "executes the command on quit
     autocmd VimLeave *.cpp !your_command

    "execute the command on write
    autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost *.cpp !your_commad
augroup END
```

Answer (score 2):

Auto-commit on exit sounds like a bad idea. You're essentially encouraging your own bad practices.

To commit from within vim you'd do it the same way you execute any other command:

```
 :!git commit -m "look ma I remembered to commit" my_dir/my_file.c
```

After running:

```
 :w
```

to save it ofc

Comment: The [fugitive plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) provides excellent git integration for vim.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create your own command ?
I m not already familliar with it but it must look like in your vimrc :

```
command Wc w | Gcommit
```

And then after editing your file, type :Wc

```
Wc "custom name for Write commit
Gcommit " it s a command that exist from the excellent vim plugin 'fugitive' written by tpope
| "(pipe) allow you to add a second command
w " write
```

Answer (score 0):

The [vcscommand.vim - CVS/SVN/SVK/git/hg/bzr integration plugin](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=90) provides a `:VCSCommit` command.

To hook into when a file is closed, you can use an `:autocmd` on the `BufDelete` event.

But I agree with Nanzikambe that this is a bad idea, and you should work on improving your practices instead. For example, there are plugins that can show the working copy dirty state in Vim's *statusline*, and several blog posts explain how to add such an indicator to your shell's prompt.